# how can i add foreign key to existing class in django

Tags: django, database, class, django-models

I have two simple models of country and town:

```
from django.db import models

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
class Town(models.Model):
    belongs_to = models.ForeignKey(country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Now I would like to play around a bit... and I would like to add continent. I guess correct way from the start would be to do this:

```
from django.db import models

class Continent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Country(models.Model):
    belongs_to = models.ForeignKey(continent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
class Town(models.Model):
    belongs_to = models.ForeignKey(country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

If I do that and save the file, add continents in admin.py to admin.site.register(continent), start with makemigrations... I get this:

You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'belongs' to country without a default; we can't do that (the database needs som
ething to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:

1.) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows
with a null value for this column)  2.) Quit, and let me add a
default in models.py

I get stuck here, because I do not know what to do from here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the message you get is quite self explanatory.

You are adding the `belongs_to` field to the `country` model (classes should be named with first capital letter, like this `Country` though) but it's declared as not nullable. That is, it **must** have a value declared.

Now, because you already have some rows (objects) of the `country` model populated, Django asks you what value of `belongs_to` should add to those existing rows.

There are 2 solutions to this:

1. Add an integer (which is going to be the `id` of the `continent` model) to all of them and change it later, or
2. Change to `belongs_to = models.ForeignKey(continent, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)` so that after you `migrate` this field **can** be nullable, so existing rows will have that field as `null`.

Hope you understand.

Answer (score 3):

I have often been struggling with that. Thanks to @nik_m's answer I could figure out (after some tests and failures) the to me most trivial way to add a new ForeignKey to a model with no objects, from a model that already has objects.

1. Make the field nullable (like nik_m explained in step 2 of his answer above).
2. Create a (default) object of the foreign model. It will automatically have id=1 (if no object existed yet).
3. Change your foreignkey field by replacing `null=True, blank=True` by `default=1` to associate that new object you created to all existing rows.
4. Finally you can (eventually) remove the `default=1` to force every new object to declare the foreignkey at its creation.

Comment: This is a good explanation.

However, I am not sure I understand why you would need to make the field blank/nullable to start with, given this approach. If you provide default=1, and that object exists in the foreign table, and you only make the migration then, each existing row will be populated with foreign_object.id = 1 already.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the new `ForeignKey` field as non-nullable from the start and be able to run all migrations smoothly without errors and without the need to pause in the middle (e.g. to create foreign key records), you can include adding a new record (for the foreign key) in the migrations file:

1. Don't set `null=True` on the model's field.

   ```py
   class Country(models.Model):
       ...
       belongs_to = models.ForeignKey(continent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       ...
   ```
2. Generate the migration file.

   ```bash
   python3 manage.py makemigrations
   ```

   Choose to *"Provide a one-off default now"*. Set the default value for the referenced foreign key ID to any value, e.g. `1`. The value doesn't matter as we will change it later.

   At this point, if there are existing records in the `Country` table, running a migration would fail because setting the value for `Country.belongs_to` across all the records of `Country` to a non-existent `Continent` foreign key record (with whatever foreign key ID you set as the default value) will fail.
3. Modify the generated migration file.

   After the migration operation that defines the creation of the new `Continent` model, create a new `Continent` record in the database. Then, add the new foreign key `belongs_to` field to the `Country` model and set its value to the ID of the newly created record as the default value for the foreign key.

   - Thus, if the migration is run, the new model `Continent` table will be created, then a new `Continent` record will be created, then the new field `continent_id` foreign key will be added to the model `Country` table where each record will have its value set to the ID of the created `Continent` record.

   ```
   ...

   class _InitialContinentID:
       # Static attribute. Accessible both from class and class instances. All instances will point to
       # the same variable in memory, thus it will have a common value across all instances.
       value = None

       def __call__(self):
           return self.value


   def set_initial_continent_id(apps, schema_editor):
       # To run this migration successfully, we need a valid value for the ForeignKey 'belongs_to' of
       # the model 'Country' referencing a 'Continent' record. Thus, create a dummy 'Continent' record
       # that will be mapped to all existing countries.
       Continent = apps.get_model('appname', 'Continent')
       db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
       queryset = Continent.objects.using(db_alias)
       if queryset.exists():
           # This is not needed anymore if the model is newly created and guaranteed to be empty.
           _InitialContinentID.value = queryset.first().id
       else:
           # Create a new 'Continent' record. Later, just manually correct all 'Country' records
           # that relates to this dummy continent.
           _InitialContinentID.value = queryset.create(name="_OVERWRITE_THIS").id


   class Migration(migrations.Migration):
       dependencies = [
           ...
           # If the 'Continent' model is created in another migration file, then that migration file
           # must be a dependency here as we need to create a 'Continent' record.
           ...
       ]

       operations = [
           # If the 'Continent' model is to be created in this migration file, then create it here
           # e.g. migrations.CreateModel(name='Continent', ...)

           # Create a dummy 'Continent' record
           migrations.RunPython(set_initial_continent_id),

           # Add thew new foreign key field to 'Country' and set it to the created dummy 'Continent'
           # record.
           migrations.AddField(
               model_name='country',
               name='belongs_to',
               # The easiest option is to just set this to 'default=1' since '1' is usually the ID of
               # the 1st created record in a table. If we want to make it more dynamic, we must set
               # 'default' to a callable object, here being an instance of the class
               # '_InitialContinentID' which implements '__call__' thus making it a callable object.
               # You can't just directly set this to the (immutable) fixed (integer) value e.g.
               # 'default=_InitialContinentID().value' or 'default=_InitialContinentID.value'
               # because the original value will persist (in this example is 'None') and be stored
               # directly to the default value. If you want any updates to the original value be
               # visible, then set it to a callable object that would be called when executed and
               # retrieve the most updated value.
               field=models.ForeignKey(default=_InitialContinentID(), to='appname.continent', ...),
               ...
       ]

   ...
   ```
4. Migrate. From now onwards, you can just always safely run this migration (even on a new environments) without human intervention to manually create foreign key records.

   ```
   python3 manage.py migrate
   ```

As others have mentioned, another option is to declare the models field as nullable with `null=True`, migrate (add the field to the database), then set the field values (per record in the database), then remove `null=True` to make it non-nullable.